# JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly on Ubuntu when trying to run Ballerina code?

Tags: java, wso2, java-home, ballerina

I have already set JAVA_HOME in the environment variables file as shown below.

[image]

I also built ballerina from the **source** and extracted the zip with the **Runtime and the tools** as per the Ballerina documentation. However when I try to give this distribution as the **Ballerina SDK** in **IntelliJ IDEA** or even in the **Terminal** and try to run a Ballerina program as shown below:

[image]

I get the following error:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
```

But when I type:

`echo $JAVA_HOME`

I get the following output:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: Ballerina Version: **jballerina-tools-2.0.0-Preview3-SNAPSHOT**

Comment: That is an other JAVA_HOME pointing to the JRE subdirectory i.o. the JDK directory itself (which contains extras like tools.jar). Not sure whether set/export is needed; a question for a linux forum.

Comment: what is that env file ?

Answer (score 1):

The value of your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is wrong. It should not to point to an executable but to the location (i.e. a directory) of the Java installation.

In your case the correct value seems to be:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

See also e.g. [How to set JAVA_HOME for Java?](https://askubuntu.com/a/175547/18928).

Normal Ballerina 1.2 distribution doesn't require `JAVA_HOME` but this might be different in your case as you're building a preview release.

Comment: It took me over an hour to find this, which eventually fixed it for me. Thanks mate !!!

Answer (score 0):

what @user272735 was partly correct but you can see that I have added the **correct Java Home path** in the **environment file.** Actually the problem was that I was working on **terminator** when changing the java home path in the environment file and running the below command.

```
 source /etc/environment
```

But I was trying to run the ballerina code in the **plain-old Terminal** where the path change was **not registered yet**.

**How to resolve:**

I had to run the below command in the Terminal as well. Then when I echoed the java path it printed the one in the environment file and the ballerina code also ran without a problem.

```
source /etc/environment
```